# Angular cookies

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been looking all around for Angular cookies but I haven't been able to find how to implement cookies management in Angular. Is there any way to manage cookies (like $[cookie](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) in AngularJS)?

Comment: Angular2 doesn't have any native library/service to handle cookies. The preferred way is to use JWT/LocalStorage. https://github.com/auth0/angular2-authentication-sample

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I ended creating my own functions:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cookie-consent',
    template: cookieconsent_html,
    styles: [cookieconsent_css]
})
export class CookieConsent {
    private isConsented: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        this.isConsented = this.getCookie(COOKIE_CONSENT) === '1';
    }

    private getCookie(name: string) {
        let ca: Array<string> = document.cookie.split(';');
        let caLen: number = ca.length;
        let cookieName = `${name}=`;
        let c: string;

        for (let i: number = 0; i < caLen; i += 1) {
            c = ca[i].replace(/^\s+/g, '');
            if (c.indexOf(cookieName) == 0) {
                return c.substring(cookieName.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    private deleteCookie(name) {
        this.setCookie(name, '', -1);
    }

    private setCookie(name: string, value: string, expireDays: number, path: string = '') {
        let d:Date = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + expireDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        let expires:string = `expires=${d.toUTCString()}`;
        let cpath:string = path ? `; path=${path}` : '';
        document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; ${expires}${cpath}`;
    }

    private consent(isConsent: boolean, e: any) {
        if (!isConsent) {
            return this.isConsented;
        } else if (isConsent) {
            this.setCookie(COOKIE_CONSENT, '1', COOKIE_CONSENT_EXPIRE_DAYS);
            this.isConsented = true;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make it an injectable next time :)

Comment: Maybe you could post your own solution with injectable functionality, that would be great for others needing it injectable :)

Comment: Does this have to be a component? Why don't you make it an injectable service?

Comment: Could be, but this has also html and css to show consent banner. It seems more like a component than a service. You could make a service also, but should be a more abstracted one :)

Comment: I have created the injectable service based on the above answer : https://gist.github.com/greatb/c791796c0eba0916e34c536ab65802f8

Comment: What does the `\+` mean in method getCookie? It seems like you wanted to match one or more whitespaces, in which case you should use `+`, without escaping it (now you are searching for the _plus_ character after the whitespace, so this code hardly finds an existent cookie).

Comment: @mariogl hmm, maybe you're right... Could you confirm that this is working with replacing `\+` by `+`? This is more a year old and maybe if you're using this code you could debug it. In fact it needs a review and maybe a github repo, you'll probably want to check @Bala repo to see if there is an issue there too

Comment: @Miquel I tried your regex and the getCookie method always returned "", even when the cookie existed (my cookie string has a whitespace at the beggining). But it works with the proposed change. You can see it in this 
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tnjqEOSYjbCOoTlTI8RM?p=preview). I can see now that a commenter at Bala's repo has reported it too.

Comment: @mariogl thanks, i've fixed it and improved strings concatenation to improve readability :)

Comment: I have updated the Injectable CookieService gist accordingly, as well.

Comment: Works great! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It will be stored in the browser or in memory of app where angular is hosted? Can it be accessed in other angular application of different subdomain? Like localstorage, we can share among sub-domain using the header in response Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=mydomain.com?

Comment: Nice !  Instead of document.cookie.split   use var decoded =decodeURIComponent(document.cookie); and then decoded.split

Comment: How to set HttpOnly and secure flags ?

Answer (score 44):

**Update:** [angular2-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie) is now deprecated. Please use my [ngx-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie) instead.

***Old answer:***

Here is [angular2-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie) which is the exact implementation of Angular 1 `$cookies` service (plus a `removeAll()` method) that I created. It is using the same methods, only implemented in typescript with Angular 2 logic.

You can inject it as a service in the components `providers` array:

```
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-very-cool-app',
    template: '<h1>My Angular2 App with Cookies</h1>',
    providers: [CookieService]
})
```

After that, define it in the consturctur as usual and start using:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private _cookieService:CookieService){}

  getCookie(key: string){
    return this._cookieService.get(key);
  }
}
```

You can get it via npm:

```
npm install angular2-cookie --save
```

Comment: Which is the difference with ng2-cookies?

Comment: It is using the angular 1 logic and methods behind the scenes. So it is in more angular way. Also it has all the methods from $cookies service, plus a remove all method. Also it provides global and parameter options. And it is a service.

Comment: ngx-cookie doesn't seem to be updated anymore either.

Comment: It it finally updated. The dev was busy with other stuff and he is also a little bit lazy :D

Answer (score 26):

Use **NGX Cookie Service**

Inastall this package: `npm install ngx-cookie-service --save`

Add the cookie service to your app.module.ts as a provider:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ... ],
  providers: [ CookieService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Then call in your component:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.cookieService.set( 'name', 'Test Cookie' ); // To Set Cookie
  this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('name'); // To Get Cookie
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Hi Deepak, have you worked with this service so far? Because I've a question and hope you can help me.

Comment: I've installed both the ngx-service and cookie consent. I'm now struggling hard with implementing it the opt-in way. I've tried deleting all cookies if the user presses the decline cookies button but they're getting re-set somehow. So do you know how this should be done the correct way?

Comment: This is my question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656421/how-can-i-block-cookies-for-beeing-stored-in-the-browser-in-angular

Comment: It seems the version `10.1.1` creates error `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`. I use version `2.1.0` to get the code working. Check  https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/103

Comment: @ManuChadha Did you check your solution regarding to different subdomains? If you set a cookie for example to domain.com, will you have the same cookie available for subdomain.domain.com ?

Comment: Thanks @ManuChadha, v-2.1.0 has no issue. I am working on angular 6

Answer (score 13):

Yeah, here is one 
ng2-cookies

Usage:

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

Cookie.setCookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue');
Cookie.setCookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', 10 /*days from now*/);
Cookie.setCookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', 10, '/myapp/', 'mydomain.com');

let myCookie = Cookie.getCookie('cookieName');

Cookie.deleteCookie('cookieName');
```

Comment: Their API has changed here are the docs: https://github.com/BCJTI/ng2-cookies/wiki/Minimum-running-example

Answer (score 8):

I make Miquels Version Injectable as service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CookiesService {

    isConsented = false;

    constructor() {}

    /**
     * delete cookie
     * @param name
     */
    public deleteCookie(name) {
        this.setCookie(name, '', -1);
    }

    /**
     * get cookie
     * @param {string} name
     * @returns {string}
     */
    public getCookie(name: string) {
        const ca: Array<string> = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(';');
        const caLen: number = ca.length;
        const cookieName = `${name}=`;
        let c: string;

        for (let i  = 0; i < caLen; i += 1) {
            c = ca[i].replace(/^\s+/g, '');
            if (c.indexOf(cookieName) === 0) {
                return c.substring(cookieName.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * set cookie
     * @param {string} name
     * @param {string} value
     * @param {number} expireDays
     * @param {string} path
     */
    public setCookie(name: string, value: string, expireDays: number, path: string = '') {
        const d: Date = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + expireDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        const expires = `expires=${d.toUTCString()}`;
        const cpath = path ? `; path=${path}` : '';
        document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; ${expires}${cpath}; SameSite=Lax`;
    }

    /**
     * consent
     * @param {boolean} isConsent
     * @param e
     * @param {string} COOKIE
     * @param {string} EXPIRE_DAYS
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    public consent(isConsent: boolean, e: any, COOKIE: string, EXPIRE_DAYS: number) {
        if (!isConsent) {
            return this.isConsented;
        } else if (isConsent) {
            this.setCookie(COOKIE, '1', EXPIRE_DAYS);
            this.isConsented = true;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How to set HttpOnly and secure flags ?

Answer (score 4):

It is also beneficial to store data into `sessionStorage`

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

for details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 1):

For read a cookie i've made little modifications of the Miquel version that doesn't work for me:

```
getCookie(name: string) {
        let ca: Array<string> = document.cookie.split(';');
        let cookieName = name + "=";
        let c: string;

        for (let i: number = 0; i < ca.length; i += 1) {
            if (ca[i].indexOf(name, 0) > -1) {
                c = ca[i].substring(cookieName.length +1, ca[i].length);
                console.log("valore cookie: " + c);
                return c;
            }
        }
        return "";
```

Answer (score 0):

My simplest CookieService, support reading only

```
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CookieService {

    public constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { }

    public get(name: string) {
        const cookies = this.document.cookie.split('; ')
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const [key, value] = cookies[i].split('=');
            if (key === name) {
                return decodeURIComponent(value);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```