# How to use Cookie Service in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to delete the exact cookie, but cannot install appropriate package to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide us some more information about what you tried, what doesn't work etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298133/angular-cookies)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please do a bit of googling and get your hands dirty. Then post your specific issue so that we can help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use ngx-cookies.**

```
# To get the latest stable version and update package.json file:
npm install ngx-cookie --save
# or
# yarn add ngx-cookie
```

**After installing the library, it should be included in the SystemJS configurations.**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 * Taken from: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
      'ngx-cookie':                 'npm:ngx-cookie/bundles/ngx-cookie.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**Usage**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, CookieModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-very-cool-app',
    template: '<h1>My Angular2 App with Cookies</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private _cookieService:CookieService){}

  getCookie(key: string){
    return this._cookieService.get(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngx-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie). Refer the documentation [here](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie#readme) for installing and setting up

There are [different methods](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie#-cookieservice) for getting, removing etc. You can use them as per your needs