# How can I block cookies for beeing stored in the browser in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I'm currently building a little angular page. In this page I'm using `ngx-cookieconsent` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookieconsent) for handling the cookies.

Everything works but now I'm a little bit confused. I've set it up with the parameter `opt-in` but when I visit the page first, there are already cookies stored in the browser even if I press decline or nothing:

[image]

Thats really confusing. I've also tried subscribing to the status change of the consent:

```
this.statusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
  (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
    console.log('Changed');
  });
```

But I still don't know why there are cookies before and how I can block them again if the user presses the decline button.

Does anyone can explain this please?

Comment: First find out what are those 23 Cookies; Chrome will show you: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies/
If those are not *your* cookies, then do you really have a problem?