# Add custom cookies using ngx-cookieconsent

Tags: angular, cookies

I am trying to set custom cookies and not just `cookieconsent_status` so when the user clicks accept it should also show `mycustomCookie` name to set to yes, This is currently what i got:

```
const cookieConfig: NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  cookie: {
    domain: environment.cookieDomain,
    expiryDays: 364,
    name: 'law_info_viewed_cookie'
  },
  position: 'bottom',
  palette: {
    popup: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      text: '#1f2122',
      link: '#1f2122'
    },
    button: {
      background: '#002850',
      text: '#ffffff',
      border: 'transparent'
    }
  },
  theme: 'classic',
  type: 'opt-out',
  content: {
    message : 'We use cookies on our website to give you the most relevant experience by remembering your preferences and repeat visits. By clicking “Accept”, you consent to the use of ALL the cookies.',
    dismiss : 'Got it!',
    deny : 'Deny cookies',
    link : 'Learn more',
    href : '/cookies',
    policy : 'Cookie Policy'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to set custom cookies but it doesn't look like that is in the scope of ngx-cookieconsent, based on a quick glance at their [documentation](https://tinesoft.github.io/ngx-cookieconsent/doc/index.html).

You'll likely have to set them yourself or with another library. The simplest approach is likely to just write a small injectable service that can set/get cookies. To set a custom cookie all you need is something like this,

```
  document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; ${expires}${cpath}${domain}; `;
```

Here is a similar question that may be helpful,

[Angular cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298133/angular-cookies)