# How to add the cookies in the static page using the angular

Tags: angular

I was created the static website for the portfolio and i have want to add the cookies in the their project. but i don't have knowledge how to add the cookies in the static website, any one can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't provide a way to work with cookies by default. The preferred way is using webStorage. But you can check [ngx-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie) package if you need.

Possible duplicate question for [Angular cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298133/angular-cookies).

Comment: Thanks, can you share my process of ngx-cookies?